# How to control a spark Datagrid's scroller position in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4, scrollbar

I'm using the new Spark Datagrid for a project, but I must confess the scroller is annoying me a little bit, so I would like to have some control over it.

In other words, I would like to programatically set the Datagrid scroller position to the position I want.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the links above are useful to get to the answer, here is the direct answer:

```
someDataGrid.grid.layout.verticalScrollPosition
```

Answer (score 6):

1. [Setting the horizontal scroll position in the HorizontalList control in Flex](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/04/03/scrolling-the-horizontallist-control-in-flex/)
2. [Setting the vertical scroll position on a Spark List control in Flex 4](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/05/30/setting-the-vertical-scroll-position-on-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/)
3. [Programmatically scrolling the Spark TextArea control in Flex 4](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/02/18/programmatically-scrolling-the-spark-textarea-control-in-flex-4/)
4. [Flex 4 List remembering verticalScrollPosition](http://flex4examples.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/flex-4-list-remembering-verticalscrollposition/)
5. [Scroll automatically to the bottom of a Container or TextArea](http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2007/08/20/scrolling-to-the-bottom-of-a-container-or-textarea-automatically/)

hope these links will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use ensureCellIsVisible

```
datagrid.ensureCellIsVisible(dgArrayCollection.length - 1,-1);
```

where dgArrayCollection is the dataprovider of the datagrid